# Improve the performance of this script

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, shiny

Here is a piece of my code that I introduce in an R shiny application but which takes me a lot of time because I execute it in a reactive function which I then call five times for different graphics.

Do you have an idea to improve the speed of this script?

I have already tried to execute this with purr but I do not master this tool well enough.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(profvis)
profvis({

#dataframe created for the example

DF<- data.frame("scan"=seq(1:7518),"dye1"=NA,"dye2"=NA,"dye3"=NA,"dye4"=NA,"dye5"=NA,"dye6"=NA)
DF$dye1 <- sample(100, size = nrow(DF), replace = TRUE)
DF$dye2 <- sample(100, size = nrow(DF), replace = TRUE)
DF$dye3 <- sample(100, size = nrow(DF), replace = TRUE)
DF$dye4 <- sample(100, size = nrow(DF), replace = TRUE)
DF$dye5 <- sample(100, size = nrow(DF), replace = TRUE)
DF$dye6 <- sample(100, size = nrow(DF), replace = TRUE)


#slowness begins here

for (d in 3000:7518){

  #array of input data
  input <- numeric(1206)

  for (i in -100:100){
    input[1+i+100] <- DF$dye1[d + i]
    input[202+i+100] <- DF$dye2[d + i]
    input[403+i+100] <- DF$dye3[d + i]
    input[604+i+100] <- DF$dye4[d + i]
    input[805+i+100] <- DF$dye5[d + i]
    input[1006+i+100] <- DF$dye6[d + i]
  }
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: please **really** reconsider what you want to achieve and whether this approach is the smartest way to achieve it..

Second: use vectorization to improve your performance:

```
d <- 3000
input <- numeric(1206)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  # loop as before
  case1 = {for (i in -100:100){
    input[1+i+100] <- DF$dye1[d + i]
  }},
  # use vectorization
  case2 = {input[(1-100+100):(1+100+100)] <- DF$dye1[(d -100):(d +100)]}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I set up this model to adapt the five graphics (dye1, dye2 ...) in the form of an image like the MNIST dataset to carry out deep learning thereafter. I'm still having trouble using vectorization. I don't yet have the logic in mind for the moment.

Comment: Yes, thank you ! I will now try to apply vectorization on this loop : `d <- 3000        for (i in 4:1209){DF2[d-2999, 1+i] <- input[i]} ` I hope this is possible.